# Default workspace preferences

Tags: eclipse

Each time when I create a new workspace I have to set the workspace preference "Save automatically before build" for each workspace. Further I have several workspace that I didn't touch until now and I don't want to miss this option.

- How can I set this default preference?
- Can I set this preference global for all workspaces?

I have two Eclipse installations. One (CCS) enables this by default the other come with disabled be default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences are stored in the workspace, therefore it is not possible to store global preferences for all workspaces.

What you can do:

- Export your preferences and import the resulting file into your other workspaces
- Copy the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder from one of your old workspaces into any new workspace you create

See also [Setting preferences for all Eclipse workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933882/setting-preferences-for-all-eclipse-workspaces?rq=1) and [Maintaining a common set of Eclipse preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951509/maintaining-a-common-set-of-eclipse-preferences?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, I can't change old workspaces. Although your solution with export/import doesn't use really less clicks than setting the checkbox in each workspace. -- How can I tell Eclipse to enable this per default.