# Eclipse not finding std c++ libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a Windows8 machine with mingw installed in c:\mingw
Eclipse does successfully compile programs, but it considers lines to contain errors that are fine when compiled.  Eclipse is not finding the libraries itself.

When I first build a project in eclipse with the CDT components install, it shows errors on every #include and every line using an object.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "hello\n";
}
```

The above code shows errors on the include, the using and the cout << line.
I can get rid of the errors by clicking:
project->properties C++/General Preprocessor Include
Then on the providers tab, I can check off "CDT Build output parser" and fix the mistakes as described by the first answer below, which I am upchecking.  But this only works for the project.  I have to do this every time.  How can I get eclipse to simply accept standard C++ EVERY TIME I build a new project without reconfiguring each project?

I have been able to stop errors on the includes by going into project settings and adding the directories:

c:/bin/mingw/lib/gcc/include
...

That leaves the errors on lines using the objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "this is a test.";
    regex e("est");
    smatch m;
```

The line with regex still shows an error: "type regex could not be resolved"
even though the code compiles and the regex include is recognized.

Additionally, on a different machine running windows 8.1 with Mingw installed, eclipse will not debug.  Is there some document on how to connect Eclipse CDT to the library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you obviously successfully compile the code with gcc from within Eclipse, Eclipse has its own built-in C++ parser and you need to separately let it know that you are using C++11.

Add the `-std=c++11` option to the `CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings` under `Project propierties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths`, the compiler specs should look similar to this:

```
${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD ${INPUTS} -std=c++11
```

---

**UPDATE.** Please read **[Setting Up Include Paths and Macros for C/C++ Indexer](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/october/article4.php)** to understand how CDT automatic discovery of include paths and preprocessor symbols (aka Scanner Discovery) for supported tool chains is applicable to you.

The gist is that the CDT uses the `Language Settings Providers` to find include paths and preprocessor symbols. And `Language Settings Providers` can be configured on project properties page `"Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc."`

Once you have proper settings you can make them a template workspace and just copy the template workspace over for your new projects, or alternatively have a script that will set up just the relevant settings. Also see: [Setting preferences for all Eclipse workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933882/setting-preferences-for-all-eclipse-workspaces).

Comment: Perhaps I should give an example that doesn't use C++11. I get these errors with much more mundane object, like cout!

Comment: I changed the question to make this clearer.  Your answer led me to a partial answer: I can edit the project to recognize headers, but why do I have to do that every time? I want eclipse to recognize standard stuff (forget C++11) every time.  I should not have to click down into project settings to get it to recognize #include <iostream>

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Eclipse underlined like an error a regex keyword, but project was built without errors. I chose a Language Dialect as "`ISO C++1y (-std=c++1y)`" in `Properties->C/C++ Build->GCC C++ Compiler->Dialect Language Standart`

Answer (score 0):

Been a while, but adding in case someone else finds this answer as I did.

I had what appeared to be this issue but it turned out that while I had installed MinGW, eclipse still expected me to have installed cygwin. Go to project properties > C/C++ Build > Tool Chain Editor > Current Toolchain and select the appropriate option.
Not sure why it defaults the setting to a toolchain it can't find.